# add wordpress filter error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am declaring this filter in my function.php file:

```
<?php
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes');

function posts_link_attributes() {
    return 'class="styled-button"';
}
?>
```

but get this back:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare posts_link_attributes() (previously
>   declared in functions.php in index.php)

Because I use next_post_link() in index.php

Is there a solution for this? a reason this doesn't work?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the callback more specific.

```
<?php
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes_style_button');

function posts_link_attributes_style_button() {
    return 'class="styled-button"';
}
?>
```

To test if a function exists:

```
if(function_exists('posts_link_attributes')){

}
```

Comment: awesome thanks that works! I didn't know it was already "used" :).

Comment: @SnippetSpace No prob. Just added how to check if a function exists.

Comment: just did! had to wait for the time limit

Answer (score 0):

Change your function name to something else:

```
<?php
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'my_posts_link_attributes');

function my_posts_link_attributes() {
    return 'class="styled-button"';
}
?>
```